# What is the best way to store data securely?

Tags: android, database, sharedpreferences, access-token

What is the best way to store data securely?

We all know that there is no complete security.

I receive information from a web service.This information includes access-token and refresh-token.
Now this token must be stored and available whenever needed.But it should not be easily accessible to hackers.

I researched about databases and shared preferences, Each has its pros and cons.

What type of storage is more secure for storing sensitive information?

Thank you dear friends

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [EncryptedSharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences) . It's basically shared preferences but it automatically encrypts data.